# Sidebar 100vh does not stretch

Tags: css

I use a sidebar with a height of 100vh. when the content becomes longer and it is necessary to scroll down, the `sidebar` does not extend along the page, but remains at the original height. How can I solve?

```css
html {
  line-height: 1.15;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans- serif;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  min-height: 100%;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
}

.sidebar {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #c7cdd1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sidebar"></div>
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: your code doesn't show any sidebar. please organize and complete your code then put it in a snippet so we can see the issue and help you.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by setting the height to 100% with absolute position

Answer (score 0):

**Explanation:** ***(Read this carefully to understand code better!!!)***

You have to assign the width property to the sidebar and the content first.
I said `content` is going to have a `width: 65%;` property, and `.sidebar` is going to have a `width: 35%;` property. If their total widths are going to make **100%** now they are not going to have space between them.

Then we have to use float property so they can be side by side. Otherwise, the sidebar will be under the content. So we have to do : `.content{float: left;}` and `.sidebar{float: right;}`
Then they are completely divided by 35-65% and whatever you assign the containers height property they will keep extending by that.
Hope I helped.

Check out the code below to understand the explanation carefully.

```css
html {
  line-height: 1.15;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans- serif;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: black;
}

.container {
  height: 500px;
}
.content {
  background-color: pink;
  height: 500px;
  width: 60%;
  float: left;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.sidebar {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 500px;
  width: 40%;
  float: right;
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sidebar">This is sidebar</div>
  <div class="content">This is content</div>
</div>
```